# Angular Controller Mock is not perisisting in my Mocha test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, karma-mocha

Currently running Angular 1.2.x with karma-mocha 0.2.0 and karma-chai 0.1.0.

The following is my attempt to write some simple Unit Tests for my `MentorAvailabilityDashboardCtrl` which is based off the `Mentors` module. Everything passes when individually run, but when I run the test as is I get an error stating "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MentorAvailabilityDashboardCtrl' is not a function, got undefined"

It makes me think that Mocha or the AngularMock gets reset after the test get run once and is undefined after.

#### Example:

Test running all at once

- 1st test = Pass
- 2nd test = Fail "MentorAvailabilityDashboardCtrl got undefined"
- 3rd test = Fail "MentorAvailabilityDashboardCtrl got undefined"
- 4th test = Fail "MentorAvailabilityDashboardCtrl got undefined"

Testing running all at once (commenting other test out)

- 1st test = Pass
- 2nd test = Pass
- 3rd test = Pass
- 4th test = Pass

#### Question:

Why is my controller going undefined after the first test run and Is there anything I can do have it persist for each test run?

#### My Code:

```
'use strict';
/* globals gon: false */

import angular from 'angular';

describe('MentorAvailabilityDashboardCtrl', function() {
  let createController, $scope;

  beforeEach(function() {
    angular.module('Mentors', []);
    require('./mentor_availability_dashboard')
    angular.mock.module('Mentors');
  });

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
      function MockMentorProfile() {}
      function MockFlash() {}

      $scope = $rootScope.$new()
      createController = $controller('MentorAvailabilityDashboardCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope,
        MentorProfile: MockMentorProfile,
        Flash: MockFlash
      });
  }));

  describe('validation checks', function() {
    it('should invalidate form fields on initialization', function() {
      expect($scope.validatedFields()).to.eq(false);
    });

    it('should validate specifc field on initialization', function() {
      $scope.courseFilter = 'Rails';

      expect($scope.fieldValidated($scope.courseFilter)).to.eq(true);
    });

    it('should validate form fields on completion', function() {
      $scope.courseFilter = 'Rails';
      $scope.osFilter = 'Windows';
      $scope.studentFilter = { student: 'Billy' };
      $scope.paceFilter = '12 weeks';
      $scope.startFilter = { monday: 'Monday' };

      expect($scope.validatedFields()).to.eq(true);
    });

    it('should be able to click form with clearForm()', function() {
      $scope.courseFilter = 'Rails';
      $scope.clearForm()

      expect($scope.courseFilter).to.eq('');
    });
  });

});
```

#### Actual Error:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) MentorAvailabilityDashboardCtrl "before each" hook: workFn for "should validate specifc field on initialization" FAILED
    Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MentorAvailabilityDashboardCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/ng/areq?p0=MentorAvailabilityDashboardCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
        at assertArg (/Users/bdoug/Bloc/vendor/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1509)
        at assertArgFn (/Users/bdoug/Bloc/vendor/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1520)
        at /Users/bdoug/Bloc/vendor/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7278
        at /Users/bdoug/Bloc/frontend/test/tests_index.js:15072 <- webpack:///frontend/legacy_org/mentors/mentor_availability_dashboard.test.js:23:8
        at invoke (/Users/bdoug/Bloc/vendor/assets/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3966)
        at workFn (/Users/bdoug/Bloc/vendor/assets/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2161)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are requiring the controller definition in a beforeEach block and that might have something to do with it. Probably a scoping issue. You might try avoiding angular mocks alltogether and just test the controller function directly. Since you are using es6 modules you can export the controller function directly as a named export.

```
export function MyController($scope, Flash) {
 //...
}

MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Flash'];

angular.module('Mentors').controller('MyController')
```

Then in the test

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import {MyController} from './my_controller'


it('...', function() {
  let scope = {};
  let Flash = sinon.mock();

  MyController(scope, Flash);

  //... assertions
})
```

Comment: I get the following error Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Mentors' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: turns out I just needed to add the `..., [])`